# Migrate MS Access back-end to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms, database-migration

I am incredibly frustrated!

I have been trying for months to migrate a MS Access database to SQL Server and nothing has worked. I need to be able to edit data on an Access front-end and the SQL Server back-end.

I've been able to copy a table, but edits on one end are not applied on the other. I'm severely limited in what applications I can download -- it takes at least a week for our IT department to install a new app. I've tried using SSMS 18 (just had it installed today) to create a linked service.

I use "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access ..." (16.0 is not available) as the Provider and leave Product Name and Provider String blank -- I get this error for either a `.mdb` or a `.accdb` file.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do
> you want to keep the linked server?
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "2022_08_24".
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7302) For help, click:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-7302-database-engine-error

The generated script is

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'2022_08_24', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'C:\Users\liptonj1\OneDrive - Southern California Edison\Documents\Word Test_be.accdb'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'2022_08_24', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'2022_08_24', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False'
GO
```

Comment: I've never heard of anyone connecting MSAccess to SQL Server as a linked server. Are you sure this is possible? Or did you just come up with the idea on your own and try it? Otherwise, there are some tools, strategies for migrating Access to SQL Server - you would want to do some research and follow the best approach you can find.  For instance: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/migrate/guides/access-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16, https://www.accessrepairnrecovery.com/blog/convert-or-migrate-access-database-to-sql-server and so on (google *Migrate Access to SQL Server*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is ALSO a 3rd option.

Access 2010 was the LAST version of Access to have a built in SQL server migration tool.

So here we are in 2022  12 years later!!!

but, Access 2010, and in fact Access 2007? It has a BUILT IN migration tool!!!

This is on the 2007 menu:

[image]

So, AFTER 2010, you ARE strong suggested to use the SSMAA - a seperate download and install.

However, Access 2003, 2007, and 2010? They have a BUILT-IN migration tool to sql server.

I don't have a 15 year old version of Access kicking around anymore, but you may very well want to try and use that tool. Just make sure you DO NOT use or pick the "ADP" option.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.  I really appreciate it, but I'm hoping I can get SSMAA installed. 

If I can't, I'll definitely use your answer.

Comment: For starting out, the built in data migration system in Access was not all that bad. I not used it for a good many years, but hey, if that tool works, and is part of access, then that would be my first choice, since you don't have to install anything at all! So, I would give that built in migration tool a try. As noted, it is not included in ms-access anymore, but at one time, Access did have a built in migration tool - and A2007 is one such version that has this feature.

Comment: I've installed SSMAfA and migrated a database... once.  After that I keep getting an error.  Please see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532211/when-i-migrate-ms-access-to-sql-server-why-do-i-get-this-error

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The right process is the one implemented by SSMA for Access: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255

After creating matching tables and migrating the data the last step is to replace the Access tables with ODBC linked tables to the SQL Server so your Access-based forms and reports work directly with the SQL Server data.

Having a linked server from SQL Server to Access is not needed.

Comment: Thanks but downloading apps is very difficult -- I'll try the answer that @PeterSmith provided first.

Comment: Yes.  My intent was just to outline the process if you can't get the tool.  Note the import wizard will not recreate your indexes, primary keys and foreign keys.  You'll have to do that manually.

Comment: How do I replace the Access tables with ODBC linked tables to the SQL Server?

Comment: Delete the tables and add them back using the ODBC linked table manager.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797

Comment: I'm sorry to impose on your time, but I think I'm pretty dense...
 --  Why do I export/import the tables, just to delete them? -- Using Import > ODBC Database > [saved.dsn] imports the tables as linked, but I can't edit them in ACCESS.
 -- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the SQL Server tables all have primary keys?  Did you create them with IDENTITY columns or SEQUENCES for any AUTOINCREMENT column in Access?  You may want to focus on getting SSMA.

Comment: No primary keys; not created with IDENTITY columns or SEQUENCES for any AUTOINCREMENT column.  SSMA isn't on the list of available software, so I'll have to do a special request to get it.  Hopefully it will be worth the bother.  Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I tested SSMAfA on my home computer and the link was quick and easy. Now all I have to do is convince my company to invest in this too.

I'm marking the answer provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10527/albert-d-kallal as the "best answer" since he provided more information.  But I really appreciate your time and wish I could mark them both as "best".

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer but is too long for a comment.

Try the following steps:

1. Using SSMS create a database
2. With that database (right mouse click) use task/import data and connect to your Access database using the Access connection type
3. Select the table(s) to copy (and copy them)
4. In your Access front end, connect to the SQL Server database using an ODBC connection and link the source tables

You can then read/write to them directly

Comment: How do I connect to the SQL Server database using an ODBC connection?

Comment: Depends on which version of Access you are using but basically use the External Data/Import and Link; select the SQL server option and use link with either FDS or MDS. Details are very much a local issue.

Comment: I tried using Import > ODBC Database > [saved.dsn] imports the tables as linked, but I can't edit them in ACCESS.  If I just use the imported tables, the Link  Manager isn't available.

Comment: You of course create a link. If the linked table works, but does not allow Edit??? then see my post below. You have to add a PK setting (primary key) to ALL tables on SQL server. While Access does not necessary require a PK setting, SQL server tables do if you going to edit from Access.

Answer (score 1):

While often not the case, we assume that you have a split access database.

That means that you have  so called front end (accdb, or mdb). (FE)
And then you have linked tables to a back end (accDB, or mdb). (BE)

And office 12? Ok, that is version 2007 - 15 years old, but should work just fine.
(what other software are you using that is 15 years old? Or are you for some strange reason singling out Access for such a old version???).

Regardless?

So, the basic idea here?

You migrate the tables from the BE to sql server.

You then delete your FE links that point to the Access back end, and now are to create links in your FE that point/link to SQL server (where you presumably) migrated the Access data tables.

Hence:

> I've been able to copy a table, but edits on one end are not applied on the other.

Sounds like your FE is still pointing to the older database. I mean EVEN without SQL server, it was often VERY easy to have your FE point to the WRONG database BE. You start editing, and you don't see changes in the database!!!!

So, once you move data to SQL server, then in your FE, you are to delete links
(you are NOT deleting tables here, but ONLY the linked tables in the FE, right, since we DO NOT have tables in the FE, do we?).

> > why do I export/import the tables, just to delete them?

You are NOT deleting tables!!!! - you are to delete your "linked" tables, or the so called links in your Access FE. You are now not using the BE anymore, and editing of data in your access FE will be directly working against and editing the table(s) that reside on SQL server. There is no concpet of suffeling data between tables - you are using linked tables. The data does NOT exist in the FE, and it never did with linked tables. So, you are being told to delete the linked tables - not the physical tables that were in your BE.

I mean assuming your Access applcation was split, then you don't have the tables in your FE to delete anymore do you? So, no, we not deleting ANY tables here, you are to delete the LINKED tables in your FE that previous pointed to your accDB BE.

You will THEN create NEW table links that now point to the tables you migrated to SQL server.

So, if you not using SSMAA?

Then you use the sql studio tools to create a database in SQL server.

Once you created a database, you are THEN to move the Access table(s) into that database. So, it comes down to what tools you plan to use for this task.

As a result, there is no "shuffle" of data between tables. You have a linked table in your FE. You are directly editing data in that linked table. But, now the linked table is not a access one, but one that resides on SQL server.

Ok, so above quite much outlines the moving parts and how this works.

So, lets take ONE simple table in a Access database. And lets import that table to SQL server. (but as noted, since this is one table, then we can use a simple import. But, AGAIN, if you have a boatload of tables in that Access database, then a dedicated migration tool is MANY times a better choice then a simple import of a table).

So, the first step would be to create a database. This is much similar to Access. You create a new database, and THEN you are to migrate(or import) the Access tables (and data) into that SQL server database.

Once done, then step 2 is to create a linked table to that table sitting in/on sql server.

So, we fire up SSMS, and create a new table.

So, we right click on databases, and choose new database.

[image]

And then just type in a name for our database.

[image]

And now hit ok.

Now, we right click on this database, and choose import data.

eg:

[image]

Now, in this example, we will import just one table.

So, in the import options, we see/get somthing like this:

[image]

Note the number of choices. Well, if this is a mdb file, then from above choose the "JET" database engine.

But, if this is a accDB file? (access 2007 and later), then choose the Access data engine as I have.

(and you might have to change the file drop down from *.mdb to all files.

So, that selects the file.

Now next page, you have to select the sql server "driver".
You have TOO many choices here - and it can be VERY confusing.

So, by FAR the best choice here is to ALWAYS choose a SQL server NATIVE driver. (you don't have to - but it will be more pain and suffering if you don't).

So this one:

[image]

thus this:

[image]

And again, don't know if you using SQL server logons, or windows security here.

Ok, so now we get:

[image]

I'm ONLY selecting one table (because this is a CRAP AND BAD way to do a data migration by using a simple import - but we have to start somewhere!!!).

So, at this point, we should be able to expland our database, and see the ONE table.

this:

[image]

Ok, so now right click on this table and choose design.

The table designer in SSMS is VERY much like access, so it should be easy to do the next steps:

REMEMBER WHAT I stated above. The import option above we used is a POOR way to import data to SQL server WHEN the goal is to use our Access FE to link to this table.

The REASON WHY is becuase the import option is kind of like a dirty and quick import choice for Excel and flat files and is quick and dirty.

But, it does NOT set our primary key, and all the other settings we would typical have in the Access table (such as PK column, and autonumber).

So, now in design mode, we WILL set the PK column.

So click on the PK column (should be in most cases "ID" - the default for Access).

Then up in the SSMS menu, click on the primary key button.

this:

[image]

Ok, that gets the PK (primary key setting).

Now we ALSO need to set this PK as "auto number" (like it was in Access).

So this setting:

[image]

So, again, "ID" is selected, and in the property sheet, set the column to "is identify" "yes", and it will put in the 1 and 1 for Increment and seed.

You can now close this table.

So, as noted, for 1 or 2-3 tables, you have to do the above for each table.

As I stated, if you have 40 and ALSO related data and tables, then we want to use a automated tool (like the SQL migration assistant for Access - SSMAA).

But, for this ONE table test, then the above is just fine.

Ok, so now we go to our Access FE, and we can delete this one table that was linked to the back end. (again, we not deleting a table, but ONLY the old existing LINKED table).

Now we create a new linked table to the SQL server table.

In access, then this:

[image]

So that option allows us to import or link (we are going to link here).

[image]

and we get to this:

[image]

ALWAYS NO MATTER what, choose (leave the default to FILE) as per above, do NOT use Machine Data source).

Next we choose the ODBC sql server driver.

WHEN POSSBILE ALWAYS choose a native driver. However, this choice depends if you going to distribute your FE to many users. (the native 11, 12 and up to 18 drivers are NOT installed by default). If  you don't see any native drivers, then choose "SQL Server", but the native drivers are a better choice (but the down side is these drivers will have to be installed on all computers. The "SQL Server" one can be a good choice, since it ALWAYS will exist on every computer).

In fact, for this lets go with SQL Server one.

So, this one:

[image]

So then this (choose a name) for the conneciton.

[image]

next, then finish, and we get this:

The drop down SHOULD show a list of SQL servers you have.

[image]

then choose your logon.

[image]

I don't know if you using windows authentication, or SQL server passwords.

Then:

SUPER SUPER IMPORTANT STEP!!!!!!!

MAKE SURE you choose your database with this drop down - don't skip this!!!!

Check the box Change the default database to box, and then choose your database we created.

[image]

This we can just hit next - nothing to change.

[image]

then this - you can (should) try the test data Source button.

[image]

Now we are all the way back to the near starting panel, and you can hit ok

[image]

And now we get/can select the table to link to:

find your table - select it, and ALSO check that save password button.

[image]

At this point, you should see a linked table in Access. If we open it, we get this:

[image]