# When I migrate MS Access to SQL Server, why do I get this error?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

I successfully linked an Access back-end to SQL Server through SSMAfA... once.  Now every time I try to migrate, on the Synchronize with the Database screen, the tables show in the Local Metadata column but are "Not Found" in the Database column.  If I click OK, I get "*Data migration was not performed because no objects were selected.*"  The tables appear in both Access and SQL Server Metadata but and I can open the table information but the Data tab says "Invalid object name 'Ledger.dbo.Categories'."

I've tried installing Access Runtime, but that didn't help.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as noted, since you using access 2007, then did you not trying the built in migration system as I suggested? It is a whole lot easier to use. But, I suppose one should not get "too" attached to the access built in migration system, since versions after 2010 do NOT have this feature (and thus you have to adopt SSMAA).

So NOT CLEAR at all why you not given the built in migration tool a try. (but, as noted, somewhat harder to get help from people here on SO, since 2007 is now 15+ years old - few are using it).

While SSMAA is a VERY good tool, it also quite a "bear" to deal with and learn (it does have a learning curve). And the more complex the access database, the BETTER choice SSMAA becomes, but then you now have to spend time learning a whole new applcation. So, for the longer term, and future skill set, then without quesiton SSMAA is a good road to take. it really comes down to how often you expect to be migrating access databases. If this is one time, not going to be done often? Then use the built in migration tool in a2007 - it rather easy and simple.

Ok, now back to your issue.

> data migration was not performed because no objects were selected

yes you have to cick on the database in the left side tree. If you don't, then EVEN if the UI shows the tables and the ones you selected? You STILL have to click on the database!

this screen shot shows how this works:

[image]

But, in fact my Migrate data is greay out!!!

So, click on the actual database in the tree left side and THEN try.

eg like this:

[image]

Now, note how my options above become "enabled".

[image]

If you don't do a simple click on the database "hotels" (which is now blue in above), then the options to migrate are not enabled.

Not sure if this is your issue - but try the above - the database on the left side in the tree has to be selected (clicked on), before most of your options will work.

Comment: I *think* I have everything selected.

Selected objects:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FVttrtBWrFU/Yw0ORsLi2OI/AAAAAAAA12Q/unIzaRvOZLQPgf_T-s-fFCtzlesD1Lx-ACNcBGAsYHQ/h120/sellected%2Bobjects.png

Sync:
!https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iADzYXs2bjs/Yw0RgOqfMtI/AAAAAAAA120/Agi-z07FCa4LLNd44tKESNfF55j9FwajQCNcBGAsYHQ/h120/new%2Bsync.png


I don't suppose there's a tutorial for how to use SSMAfA...  This tool should be a *lot* easier to work with, but it's Microsoft.

Comment: Right but after you do all that selecting, you then do what I did above - click on the data base in the tree - it has to be clicked on and highlighted as Blue in my example. It's not clear if the migration options are gray out or another issue

Comment: The migration options aren't greyed out.  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EqLMdGp8q3s/Yw0sNO_L2KI/AAAAAAAA128/KgBSLX0MljcJCJQ8W89-eABHCqZXuZ8xgCNcBGAsYHQ/h95/sync%2B2.png.  It's so frustrating to be so close and not make that last inch, especially since I did it once, but can't figure out what I did differently.

Comment: Don't right click on a table in the bottom left "meta data" area and choose sync. Anything in lower left box is ONLY for schema changes (that you might want to make to the target database).  You not trying to do that - you need to use the migrate data from menu.  Term sync in the context of the LOWER left box is ONLY for the define of the tables, or so called schema (sync schema). You use migrate data from menu bar to migrate the data. Like a export to Excel, you are over-writing the target data on sql server from the table in Access - no concept of data back and forth of data exists.

Comment: I uninstalled 64-bit SSMAfA and installed the 32-bit version instead and it worked!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good to hear.  The x32 vs x64 bit stuff is a challenge. In fact the new office defaults are now x64 bits, and for some companies, this is causing much pain. For exmample, QuickBooks and Sage accounting systems for desktop? They ONLY have x32 bit versions. So, when we build interfaces from Access to QuickBooks or Sage? We have to continue to use Access x32, and that thus is a challenge now that default installs for office are x64 bits. While the access file format does not change (both x32 and x64 bit access can use the same files, some considering for VBA code that interfaces is an issue.

Comment: I'm still getting a "No object were selected" message a lot of the time, but otherwise it "works".